# Why SparkSQL is not giving the right day of the week?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this query in SparkSQL.

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT OrderDts,
        CASE EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM OrderDts)
               WHEN 1 THEN 'Mon'
               WHEN 2 THEN 'Tues'
               WHEN 3 THEN 'Wed'
               WHEN 4 THEN 'Thu'
               WHEN 5 THEN 'Fri'
               WHEN 6 THEN 'Sat'
               WHEN 7 THEN 'Sun'
        END as dayofweek
    FROM Orders
)
SELECT * FROM a
ORDER BY OrderDts DESC
```

However, I get the wrong day name. For example, it shows me the following.

```
2021-05-10 05:58    Tues
```

While 10 May is actually Monday. Any idea why this problem occurs and how to solve it?

Comment: locale setting? (Some regions have Sunday as 1st day of week.)

Comment: @jarlh I am located in Europe.

Comment: @If week started from Saturday, then it should have got day 5 (Friday) here.

Comment: I'd expect `2021-05-10` to mean May 10th. A Monday.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, fixed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#extract) says:

> "DAYOFWEEK",("DOW") - the day of the week for datetime as Sunday(1) to
> Saturday(7) "DAYOFWEEK_ISO",("DOW_ISO") - ISO 8601 based day of the
> week for datetime as Monday(1) to Sunday(7)

So you can use `DAYOFWEEK_ISO` instead of `DAYOFWEEK`, or change the list of `when` statements.

Answer (score 1):

by the way in Hive yo could simply use this to get name of day :

```
select date_format(current_date,'EEEE');
```